# How to loop through populated rows?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The following code copies data from row 2 of sheet 'Query1' to a sheet named 'Routing Card', then prints the Routing Card, and then clears the cells.

```vb
Sheets("Routing Card").Select
Range("A2:A3").Formula = "=Query1!D2"

Range("A5:A6").Formula = "=Query1!B2"
Range("A8:A9").Formula = "=Query1!C2"
Range("A11:A12").Formula = "=Query1!J2"
Range("B11:B12").Formula = "=Query1!AE2"
Range("B1:C9").Formula = "=A5"
Range("A15:C25").Formula = "=Query1!CH2"

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Range("A2:A3,A5:A6,A8:A9,A11:A12,B11:C12,B1:C9,A15:C25").Select
Range("A15").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
```

I need to copy the third row from sheet 'Query1', print and clear cells, then row four etc. until all rows have been copied and printed.
Sheet 'Query1' is populated from an Odata direct query so will have a different row count each time the query is refreshed.

How can I loop through the rows on sheet 'Query1'?

Comment: Find last row and do a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Had a play with LastRow and Loops as suggested by findwindow.
The following appears to work!

```
Sheets("Query1").Select

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 2 To LastRow

Sheets("Routing Card").Select

Range("A2:A3").Formula = "=Query1!D" & i & ""
Range("A5:A6").Formula = "=Query1!B" & i & ""
Range("A8:A9").Formula = "=Query1!C" & i & ""
Range("A11:A12").Formula = "=Query1!J" & i & ""
Range("B11:B12").Formula = "=Query1!AE" & i & ""
Range("B1:C9").Formula = "=A5"
Range("A15:C25").Formula = "=Query1!CH" & i & ""

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Range("A2:A3,A5:A6,A8:A9,A11:A12,B11:C12,B1:C9,A15:C25").Select
Range("A15").Activate
Selection.ClearContents

    Next i
```